# Is there an elegant way to Invert a Bit value in an SQL insert Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-manipulation

I'm converting some data in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (AllowEdit)
(Select PreventEdit from SOURCETABLE)
```

so I need to inverse the bit value from source table. I expected `NOT` to work, as this is how I would do it in code, but it doesn't. The most elegant way I can think of is:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (AllowEdit)
(Select ABS(PreventEdit -1) from SOURCETABLE)
```

Is there a more standard way to do it?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I did not test this myself, but you should be able to use the [bitwise negation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173468.aspx), `~` on a bit:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (AllowEdit) 
(SELECT ~PreventEdit FROM SourceTable)
```

Answer (score 32):

[NOT or XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) if bit

```
SELECT ~PreventEdit FROM SourceTable
SELECT 1 ^ PreventEdit FROM SourceTable
```

If it isn't actually bit in SourceTable then this:

```
SELECT 1 - PreventEdit FROM SourceTable
```

Edit: A test, note NOT is 2s complement so could give odd results if not used on a bit column

```
DECLARE @bitvalue bit = 1, @intvalue int = 1;

SELECT ~@bitvalue, ~@intvalue
SELECT 1 ^ @bitvalue, 1 ^ @intvalue
SELECT 1 - @bitvalue, 1 - @intvalue

SELECT @bitvalue = 0, @intvalue = 0

SELECT ~@bitvalue, ~@intvalue
SELECT 1 ^ @bitvalue, 1 ^ @intvalue
SELECT 1 - @bitvalue, 1 - @intvalue
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot, I couldn't find this anywhere but it was probably my search terms.

Comment: In my case, XOR proved the useful approach.  I had a table where a column was labeled 'IsDeleted', but was an int, not a bit.  I was trying to convert it to IsActive as a bit.  Simply doing ~IsDeleted created a value of -2 (*definitely* not right).  So, I selected on `1 ^ IsDeleted` to get the correct IsActive value (1 ^ 1 = bit 0, 1 ^ 0 = bit 1).

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (AllowEdit)
(SELECT ~ISNULL(PreventEdit,0) FROM SourceTable)

Comment: please add a Little Information about what your code does and be sure that you Close all the paranthesis you open